# how to extract input data from a form fields and write it to a textarea in html using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

```
    The form and script are show below and I appreciate all help on this.




            $(document).ready(function(){


        function displayStory()
            {
                $('#target').toggle();
                createStory();
                //$('#create button[type="submit"]').val();

            }
            function hideStory()
            {
                $('#target').hide();

                $('#storyform input[type="text"]').val("");
                //$( "#storyform" ).resetForm();

            }

        $("#clear").click(hideStory);
        $("#create").click(displayStory);

            function createStory(){


                var userName = $("#name").val();

                var strColor = $("#color").val();

                var strAnimal = $("#animal").val();

                var strLocation = $("#location").val();

                var strFood = $("#food").val();

                var strSnacks = $("#snacks").val();


                var strSound = $("#sound").val();



                var strEmail = $("#email").val();



                var strZipCode = $("#zip").val();


                var txt1=new String("Hello, my name is " + userName + ".  My favorite color is " + strColor + ". My most cherished animal " + strAnimal + " gave me great joy. It may interest you to know that " + strAnimal + " can survive in many places including " + strLocation + "  ");
                var txt2=new String("My favorite food is " + strFood + " and I just can not get enough of it.  I can have as many as " + strSnacks + " portion(s) for snacks everyday. A sound I love is " + strSound + " and you should really hear it.  ");
                var txt3=new String("I can honestly say that my favorite email address is " + strEmail + " and I would suggest that you write to them.  If I was to pick a state that I love to live in, I would have to say one with a zip code of " + strZipCode + " would be that State.  ");


                return $("#story").html(txt1 +" "+ txt2 +" "+ txt3);

            }



        $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); },
        highlight: function(input) {
            $(input).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        },
        unhighlight: function(input) {
            $(input).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
        }
    });


    $().ready(function() {


        // validate story form on keyup and submit
        $("#storyform").validate({

               rules: {
            name:   { required: true },
            color:  { required: true,
                      minlength: 3 },
            location:  { required: true },
            animal: { required: true },
            food:   { required: true },
            sound:  { required: true },
            snacks:  { required: true, 
                      digits:   true,
                      minlength: 2, 
                      maxlength: 2 },
            email:  { required: true, 
                      email:    true },
            zip:    { required: true, 
                      digits:   true, 
                      minlength: 5, 
                      maxlength: 5 }
        },

        // messages
        messages: {
            name:   { required:  "Your name is required" },
            color:  { required:  "Color name is required",
                      minlength: "Must be at least 3 characters" },
            location:  { required:  "Location is required" },
            animal: { required:  "Animal is required" },
            food:   { required:  "Food is required" },
            sound:  { required:  "Sound is required" },
            snacks:  { required:  "Snack is required", 
                      digits:    "Must be a number",
                      minlength: "Must be 2 characters", 
                      maxlength: "Must be 2 characters" },
            email:  { required:  "Valid email address is required", 
                      email:     "Must be an email address" },
            zip:    { required:  "Zip Code is required", 
                      digits:    "Must be a number", 
                      minlength: "Must be 5 characters", 
                      maxlength: "Must be 5 characters" }
        },

        });

        });


    });


            <form class="cmxform" id="storyform" method="get" action="">

<fieldset>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First and last name" class="required"  autofocus/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="color">Color</label>
<input id="color" name="color" type="text" placeholder="enter a color" class="required"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="location">Location</label>
<input id="location" name="location" type="text" placeholder="name a location"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="animal">Animal</label>
<input id="animal" name="animal" type="text" placeholder="name an animal"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="food">Food</label>
<input id="food" name="food" type="text" placeholder="name a food"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="sound">Sound</label>
<input id="sound" name="sound" type="text" placeholder="name a sound"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="snacks">Number of Snacks</label>
<input id="snacks" name="snacks" type="number" placeholder="# of snacks"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
<input id="zip" name="zip" type="number" placeholder="5 digit zip code"/>
</fieldset>

 <div>

 <p id="target"><br/><br/>

<label for="story"><strong>Here's Your Story</strong></label><br/>
<textarea id="story" name="story" rows="3"></textarea>
</p>
</div>

<fieldset>
<button id="create"class="submit" type="submit" onclick="displayStory()" value="Create">Create</button>
<button id="clear"class="reset" type="submit" onclick="hideStory()" value="Clear"/>Clear</button>
</fieldset>


</form>

                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working here with a pretty basic script: [http://jsfiddle.net/RTfMM/](http://jsfiddle.net/RTfMM/1/).

**Update:** This will clear out all the fields within the form and replace their values with the placeholder text.

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
    $('#storyform input[type="text"]').val("");
  });
```

Comment: This is working as expected! Thanks much. Only problem is after loading the textarea the form resets automatically and clears the textarea content. Any Help with that too?

Comment: It may be because you're using `type="submit"` on the `#create` button. At that point you'd either want to use `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false;` where you're calling that form. Either that or just remove `type="submit"`.

Comment: Removing the type="submit" didn't fix it. I don't know where I am calling the form either. Anyway I have re-edited my post for your review. Thank.

Comment: `<button id="create" type="submit" onclick="return displayStory()">Create</button>` Maybe something like that would work?

Comment: Didn't fix it. how do I use event.stopPropagation() ? Or is it because the create button is part of the form? Thanks for your time with this though.

Comment: It may be because the button is in the form. In my example it isn't in the form but it's still pulling the data.

Comment: So it is working using your last code  <p>
<button id="create" type="submit" onclick="displayStory()">Create</button>
<button id="clear" type="reset" onclick="hideStory()">Clear</button>

</p>,but then I excluded the code from the form and now it does not clear the form when I click clear button.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a reset button. It'll clear all the fields within the `form` when clicked.

Comment: Voila Bravo!That did it clean. Thanks Andrew.

Comment: The final stretch is with the form validation (local) not on a server side. When I uncomment it nothing populates in the text-area nor do the buttons. However everything works when I comment it. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not so sure about that. I assume you're using a plug-in for validation? Also, what exactly needs to be validated? Maybe call the `validate()` function when `#create` is clicked?

Comment: Well the instructor thinks we should validate this form somehow on client-side. I think what you mean is right by calling the validate() function when #create is clicked. So far the form requirements do not allow the email to be without an @ sign, and a balloon displays "type an email". I don't know if other fields can also be validated. This is the instructors view;Note how the validation rules are applied as HTML value attribute pairs:

class="required" minlength="2"


So... add validation to the form for required fields, eg. numeric only zip code and 
@ sign in the email field.

Comment: For numbers you can validate that they're numerical... Other than that the most validation you could do with relative would be to check and make sure that there're values in each `input` box.

Comment: That makes sense, so I added "required" to each input element, and using $("#storyform").validate();  to enforce that. Unfortunately it appears to freeze the buttons and for that matter the text-area.

Comment: You may want to look at this:http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html on the forms. With some/most forms, you can get them to self-validate.

Comment: Hi Andrew, back with more request. I managed to add validation to the form. But it populates the text-area with both valid and invalid input data. What I need is to prevent the text-area from populating unless all input are valid. eg. email as email; number as number;...The validator currently flags all that but for allowing invalid inputs into the text-area. Also when I clear the fields it does keep previously entered email as well as all numeric fields unchanged and only clears or resets the other fields. I will update my scripts and code for your perusal. Any ideas? Thanks for your time.